# expose docker containers application port to host on windows using boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

So far I have:

1. installed boot2docker 1.6.0 on WIN7
2. created a container using ubuntu:14.01 base image
3. installed an application and committed it so that now I have a new image "demotest_core"

The issue that I am running into is that when I start my container using this command

```
docker run -it --name demotest --rm -p 127.0.0.1:15000:1500 -v /c/Users/b101/shared:/mnt/shared ubuntu/demotest_core bin/bash
```

the container starts, after that I `cd` to my application's dir and start the application (its a web application that runs on port 1500) the application starts successfully on the container and I can see it in LISTENING mode when I do `netstat`. I would like to access this app on my host WIN7 system but when I try `http://127.0.0.1:15000` I get connection refused error.

Using another terminal I can clearly see that the port mapping is in place but I am not able to access it on the host

```
C:\Users\b101>docker port demotest
1500/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:15000
```

I have also tried this command thinking that first I need to expose the PORT and then MAP it but it didn't work

```
docker run -it --name demotest --expose 1500 --rm -p 127.0.0.1:15000:1500 -v /c/Users/b101/shared:/mnt/shared ubuntu/demotest_core bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using docker-machine, that port is exposed in the VM, not your local Win7 machine.

Change `-p 127.0.0.1:15000:1500` to just `15000:1500` and then try accessing port `15000` at the IP Address given at `docker-machine ip default`.

You can't use 127.0.0.1 in the port mapping as that will only bind to the local interface which won't be accessible from outside the VM.

Comment: follow up questions
1 - Can I expose/map an application port running on a container after the container is started?
2 - How can I make a container run a script on startup, ex: copy some files from a repo/shared drive and deploy them to my app server and start the app server?

Comment: Please ask follow-up questions as new questions, not in a comment. But 1) No, at least not unless you play with IP tables etc 2) Look at ENTRYPOINT and CMD instructions in Dockerfiles

Comment: For folks living in 2016 Q1, instead of `boot2docker ip` we must now use `docker-machine ls` to spot the IP or `docker-machine ls | awk '{print $5}'`

Comment: @pulkitsinghal updated. You can just run docker-machine ip btw.